# Codeigniter 3 - A PHP Error was encountered, Severity: Notice, Message: Undefined property: Home::$home

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

I'm about to launch a website which I built with codeigniter3. I've made configuration changes such as base_url, database, etc. But it shows me an error like this :

> ````
> Message: Undefined property: Home::$home
>
> Filename: controllers/Home.php
>
> Line Number: 18
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/u8460348/public_html/application/controllers/Home.php
> Line: 18 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home/u8460348/public_html/index.php Line: 294 Function:
> require_once ```
> ````

> ````
> Message: Call to a member function select() on null
>
> Filename: /home/u8460348/public_html/application/controllers/Home.php
>
> Line Number: 18
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/u8460348/public_html/index.php Line: 294 Function:
> require_once ```
> ````

So, here is my controller :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends My_Controller
{

    public function index($page = null)
    {
        $data['title']  = 'Home | Omid Health Style';
        $data['content']    = $this->home->select(
            [
                'product.id', 'product.slug', 'product.title AS product_title', 'product.description',
                'product.image', 'product.price', 'product.is_available', 'product.weight',
                'category.title AS category_title', 'category.slug AS category_slug'
            ]
        )
            ->join('category')
            ->where('product.is_available', 1)
            ->paginate($page)
            ->get();
        $data['total_rows'] = $this->home->where('product.is_available', 1)->count();

        $this->home->table = 'blog';
        $data['blogs'] = $this->home->select(
            [
                'blog.id', 'blog.slug', 'blog.title AS blog_title', 'blog.description', 'blog.content',
                'blog.image', 'blog_category.title AS blog_category_title', 'blog_category.slug AS blog_category_slug'
            ]
        )
            ->join('blog_category')
            ->paginate($page)
            ->get();
        $data['total_rows'] = $this->home->count();

        $data['page']   = 'pages/home/index';

        $this->view($data);
    }
}
```

Here is my Home_model.php :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home_model extends MY_Model
{

    public $table    = 'product';
    protected $perPage  = 8;
}

/* End of file Home_model.php */
```

And here is in my core folder, because i made a custom configuration like this :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_Controller extends CI_Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $model = strtolower(get_class($this));

        if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'models/' . $model . '_model.php')) {
            $this->load->model($model . '_model', $model, true);
        }
    }


    // Load view with Default Layouts
    public function view($data)
    {
        $this->load->view('layouts/app', $data);
    }
}
```

If I'm running the program in my localhost, it's totally fine and works. Why do I get this error on a production server?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't get it.. What should i change exactly? could you tell me or explain to me please? but it working on my local server tho

Comment: sorry, I was looking into it too fast and came to wrong conclusion. You say it works on localhost, so most likely you need to Uppercae the model and class name: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#naming-conventions

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I appreciate that.. and yes you're right, it's about the Case Sensitivity between my model and controller.

Comment: I made my comment an asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message you received, the important part is

> Message: Call to a member function select() on null

which means your model was not loaded!

as your code works on your localhost environment, but not on the production server, most likely the error is caused by applying wrong [Naming Conventions](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#naming-conventions):

> 1. File names must be capitalized. For example: Myclass.php Class
> 2. declarations must be capitalized. For example: class Myclass Class
> 3. names and file names must match.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function __construct(){
parent::__construct()
}
```

add this to your Home controller